# Resample Pandas DataFrame on column header values (not datetime)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame which contains spectra on each row. The index is the timestamp, the column header contains the x-axis values, and the y-axis values are stored inside the DataFrame.

I would like to decrease the spectral resolution in favour of the signal-to-noise ratio by averaging several measured wavelengths together. In the data below the original resolution is 10 and I would like to bring this down to, for example, 40. This means that for each spectrum the values in columns 400, 410, 420, 430 need to be averaged and put in a column with the name 415, the values in columns 440, 450, 460, 470 need to be averaged and put in a column with the name 455, etc.

I am familiar with the function `pd.resample()`, but it seems to only work in the time domain, because when I try it with `axis=1` and the `rule=40`, I get `ValueError: Invalid frequency`.

How would one go about trying to solve this?

[image: dummy data for example]

Code for dummy DataFrame

```
#%% Import packages
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#%% Make dummy DataFrame
timestamps = pd.date_range('2023-11-07T15:00', '2023-11-07T15:10', freq='60s')
columns = np.arange(400, 1337, 10)
dummy_data = np.random.rand(len(rows), len(columns))
df_data = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data, index=timestamps, columns=columns)
```

Comment: What is "rows" in your code?

Comment: @Kirill Looks like that should be `timestamps`

Comment: So you're familiar with `resample`, but are you familiar with `groupby`? `resample` is a special case of `groupby` for time, like you said.

Comment: For random sample data, please use a seed so that results are reproducible. Or provide the random data you generated as text, [not a picture](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an [IntervalIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html) object for more general intervals that are not timestamps, and then use it to create bins in the columns. Then, groupby by axis=1 and level=0

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


timestamps = pd.date_range('2023-11-07T15:00:00', '2023-11-07T15:10:00', freq='60s')
step = 10
columns    = np.arange(400, 1337, step)
dummy_data = np.random.rand(len(timestamps), len(columns))
df_data    = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data, index=timestamps, columns=columns)

# answer starts 
freq = 40
ii = pd.interval_range(start=df_data.columns.min(),
                       freq=freq,
                       periods=(df_data.pipe(lambda x: x.columns.max()-x.columns.min()) // freq) + 1,
                       closed="left"
                      )

df_data.set_axis(ii[ii.get_indexer(df_data.columns)], axis=1)\
     .groupby(axis=1, level=0).mean().rename(columns=lambda x: (x.left + x.right - step) // 2)
```

|  | 415 | 455 | 495 | 535 | 575 | 615 | 655 | 695 | 735 | 775 | 815 | 855 | 895 | 935 | 975 | 1015 | 1055 | 1095 | 1135 | 1175 | 1215 | 1255 | 1295 | 1335 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-11-07 15:00:00 | 0.430524 | 0.521639 | 0.542988 | 0.488163 | 0.572261 | 0.525476 | 0.521687 | 0.447381 | 0.486063 | 0.241195 | 0.56868 | 0.777673 | 0.461639 | 0.494696 | 0.612861 | 0.199416 | 0.720727 | 0.322228 | 0.306663 | 0.694246 | 0.58521 | 0.573232 | 0.501292 | 0.83813 |
| 2023-11-07 15:01:00 | 0.710228 | 0.456594 | 0.504776 | 0.546193 | 0.505814 | 0.617826 | 0.322141 | 0.74073 | 0.423447 | 0.44125 | 0.436631 | 0.430491 | 0.456306 | 0.696293 | 0.592248 | 0.597835 | 0.569999 | 0.6247 | 0.338119 | 0.626863 | 0.214226 | 0.488864 | 0.455883 | 0.433434 |
| 2023-11-07 15:02:00 | 0.45061 | 0.343134 | 0.47586 | 0.633249 | 0.441403 | 0.400273 | 0.473019 | 0.53869 | 0.404705 | 0.456827 | 0.533389 | 0.582856 | 0.431298 | 0.488818 | 0.545776 | 0.232522 | 0.767286 | 0.432049 | 0.235096 | 0.544261 | 0.677255 | 0.596968 | 0.542493 | 0.453763 |
| 2023-11-07 15:03:00 | 0.500934 | 0.494954 | 0.565269 | 0.385644 | 0.564638 | 0.586023 | 0.530071 | 0.670653 | 0.252507 | 0.58376 | 0.574861 | 0.714097 | 0.309771 | 0.474184 | 0.679437 | 0.637876 | 0.529004 | 0.572173 | 0.697919 | 0.464588 | 0.617603 | 0.377916 | 0.266023 | 0.379837 |
| 2023-11-07 15:04:00 | 0.452541 | 0.421196 | 0.367973 | 0.480072 | 0.632745 | 0.337648 | 0.147384 | 0.576814 | 0.638796 | 0.49309 | 0.412712 | 0.44052 | 0.350567 | 0.742641 | 0.467432 | 0.63406 | 0.484756 | 0.558782 | 0.459106 | 0.42711 | 0.544598 | 0.727806 | 0.297389 | 0.72747 |

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341), post the text itself. You might need to print the df to get it in a good textual form.

Comment: This is very close to what I need. However, these column values cannot be used to plot spectra. Please add as a final step `df_data.set_axis(pd.Series(df_data.columns).groupby(ii.get_indexer(df_data.columns)).mean(), axis=1)` and I will accept this answer. You do, however, need the original df_data.columns, which means some renaming is required.

Comment: Now I edited so the columns names are the same as in the original

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not the solution. If the bin contains 400, 410, 420, and 430 the new column header value should be the average of those values, i.e., 415, which you achieve, for example, with my code line above.

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice the rule for the column names. I edited again.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Just a small comment, the lambda function to determine the column header values is now fixed to the step size of 10. This is okay for this example but in reality this value will change, just something to be aware of for future readers